# Im making a game called Othello, and at the end I want to iterate over the board to see who won but am running into a ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pygame

I want to iterate over a matrices and if I come across a value of 1 add it to a list and if I come across a value 2 add it to another then at the end compare the 2 lists and determine the winner.
But I am getting a error and don't understand methods any() or all().
Also looking for general improvements in the object orientated side of things since some methods I couldn't integrate them in my class.

```
    def check_game_winner(self):
        for num in self.board_body:
            if np.all(num == 1):
                self.player1_pieces.append(1)
            elif np.all(num == 2):
                self.player2_pieces.append(2)

        p1 = len(self.player1_pieces)
        p2 = len(self.player2_pieces)
        print(p1)
        print(p2)
        if p1 > p2:
            label = myfont.render("Player 1 wins!!!!", False, RED)
            self.update_screen_at_end(screen, label)
        elif p2 > p1:
            label = myfont.render("Player 2 wins!!!!", False, RED)
            self.update_screen_at_end(screen, label)
        else:
            label = myfont.render("Draw", False, RED)
            self.update_screen_at_end(screen, label)
```

Comment: please add the stacktrace of your error to the question

Comment: always put full error message (starting atword "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: when you compare `numpy array` and it doesn't know if you want to `True` when all values match or when any value match (at least one value match) - and then you have to use `(array == other).all()` or `(array == other).any()`

Comment: Before you post your code on stack-overflow please delete all of the code which does ***not*** cause the error. For example, if you have a function named `foo()`, which works just fine, then don't show us `foo()`. Try to extract at most 50 lines of which are causing you your error.

Comment: Okay can you put the all() and any() into code as a answer

Comment: And I post full code for people to see reference

Comment: And all the print statements in function check_game_winner was just me trying to figure out the problem btw

Comment: I figured it our

Comment: The values just default to 10 and 2

Comment: And the list are not appending accordingly

Comment: I put if (num == 1).any() is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) to test that all fields in a *numpy* array have the same value:

<s>`if num == 1:`</s>

```py
if np.all(num == 1):
    # [...]
```

Use [`numpy.any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) to whether any array element in a *numpy* array has a certain value:

```py
if np.any(num == 1):
    # [...]
```

---

However, if you want to count the values in a gird, you have to use 2 nested loops. Note that you have to clear the list before head:

```py
self.player1_pieces.clear()
self.player2_pieces.clear()
for row in self.board_body:
    for num in row:
        if num == 1:
            self.player1_pieces.append(1)
        elif num == 2:
            self.player2_pieces.append(2)

p1 = len(self.player1_pieces)
p2 = len(self.player2_pieces)
```

---

Alternatively you can [`flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) the multidimensional array:

```py
self.player1_pieces = []
self.player2_pieces = []
for num in self.board_body.flatten():
    if num == 1:
        self.player1_pieces.append(1)
    elif num == 2:
        self.player2_pieces.append(2)

p1 = len(self.player1_pieces)
p2 = len(self.player2_pieces)
```

---

However you don't need the `self.player1_pieces` and `self.player2_pieces` list at all. The code can be greatly simplified using  [`numpy.count_nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html):

```py
p1 = np.count_nonzero(self.board_body == 1)
p2 = np.count_nonzero(self.board_body == 2)
```

Comment: I want to iterate over it and if I find a value of 1 I want to perform a action. This action must be performed everytime I find a 1

Comment: What do I put in front of any()

Comment: Or all() can you write a example reffering to my code everytime I find a 1 I want to append a 1 to a list

Comment: I've changed the code to the part which isn't working self.board_body is the matrix can you explain why it isn't working, the lists aren't appending correctly

Comment: @Coding I've extended the answer.